# Windows - Is there a way to quickly copy the content of a file (always the same file) to clipboard

Tags: windows, keyboard-shortcuts, clipboard, file-shortcut

I'm working in a limited enterprise environement. I do stuff in ssh through Putty (cannot use any other terminal) and in my linux environment, when I do a vim yank or a tmux yank I added the behaviour that it also put the yank content in "~/.copy-buffer".

Then I created the following bat script on windows:

```
type \\path\to\linux\shared\drive\home\.copy-buffer | clip

set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
WshShell.SendKeys "^%{TAB}"
```

When run, this script will put the content of the .copy-buffer file into my Windows clipboard.
I then created a shortcut to this script, and in shortcut properties I put the bind `Ctrl+Alt+C` to it.

This works but it has 2 issues:

- It takes a few second when I press `Ctrl+Alt+C` to execute the script
- Once executed I lose focus of my current window, I have to click on it again

My question is:
Is there a way to replace the second step (the bat script) and quickly copy the content of the file without losing focus? The file can be considered a normal Windows file since it's accessible transparently through the network.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use the free [AutoHotkey](https://www.autohotkey.com/).

If I have understood your script correctly,
the following AutoHotkey script will be triggered by
<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>
and will copy your file to the clipboard, then issue
<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> to the active window :

```
^!c::
FileRead, Clipboard, \\path\to\linux\shared\drive\home\.copy-buffer
Send, ^!{Tab}
```

After installing AutoHotKey, put the above text in a `.ahk` file and
double-click it to test. You may stop the script by right-click on
the green H icon in the traybar and choosing Exit. To have it run on login,
place it in the Startup group at
`C:\Users\USER-NAME\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup`.

Useful AutoHotkey documentation:

- [List of Keys](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/KeyList.htm)
- [Hotkeys](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Hotkeys.htm)

Comment: That works much better, thank you! The alt tab part isn't even needed because with autohotkey there is no loss of focus.